# Exterior product of a direct sum.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $V=W_1\oplus W_2$, how can I show that $\wedge^n V$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{a+b=n} \wedge^a W_1 \otimes \wedge^b W_2$?

Comment: Pick a bases of $W_1$ and of $W_2$, and construct a basis of $\lambda^n V$, and look at it.

Comment: In fact they are naturally isomorphic, which is a stronger claim. You can instead show that the entire exterior algebra satisfies $\Lambda(W_1 \oplus W_2) \cong \Lambda(W_1) \otimes \Lambda(W_2)$, although it's a little tricky to do this using universal properties and $\otimes$ needs to be interpreted appropriately.